# Is there a Point class in Java?

Tags: java, point

Is there an equivalent class to Point that takes doubles in the constructor and uses double precision?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, look at the [Point2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.Double.html) class. To construct it with double values, you'd use the Double constructor:

```
Point2D myPoint = new Point2D.Double(1.0, 1.0);
```

Note that the standard Point class extends this class.

Comment: Thanks will except when I can :)